# .Net core 3.1 authorization still firing when token is expired

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, authorization

I am using JWTBearer authentication and authorization. My Startup ConfigureServices method looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.Authority = Configuration["Jwt:Authority"];
                o.Audience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];


                o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
                    {
                        c.NoResult();

                            c.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                            c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                            return c.Response.WriteAsync("An error occured processing your authentication.");
                        }
                    }
                };
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {

                options.AddPolicy("Administrator", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAssertion(x => {
                        var claimValue = x.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "resource_access").Value;
                        return claimValue.Contains("product_catalog_admin");
                    });
                });

                options.AddPolicy("Editor", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAssertion(x => x.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "resource_access").Value.Contains("product_catalog_editor"));
                });

                **options.AddPolicy("Viewer", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAssertion(x => x.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "resource_access").Value.Contains("product_catalog_viewer"));
                });**

            });

            services.AddControllers();

        }
```

Now whenever a user submits an expired token I still get an error a pasted below. One would expect that authorization would not be executed when authentication fails... The error regards the code `options.AddPolicy("Viewer", policy..`

```
app_1  | fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
app_1  |       Connection id "0HM0A710EAE69", Request id "0HM0A710EAE69:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
app_1  | System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
app_1  |    at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoMatchException()
app_1  |    at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
app_1  |    at product_catalog_api.Startup.<>c.<ConfigureServices>b__9_11(AuthorizationHandlerContext x) in /src/product-catalog-api/Startup.cs:line 143
app_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure.AssertionRequirement.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<.ctor>b__0(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
app_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure.AssertionRequirement.HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
app_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure.PassThroughAuthorizationHandler.HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
app_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, Object resource, IEnumerable`1 requirements)
app_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, Object resource)
app_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
app_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
app_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
app_1  | fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known issue?

Comment: Have you tried to set `ValidateLifetime=true` in AddJwtBearer options (options.TokenValidationParameters)?

Comment: This does not seem to solve the issue (skipping authorization). Thanks for the answer though!